# Can an "e-shock e-lean" transducer be fitted to a non-CAN-Bus equipped motor-cycle?

Tags: can-bus

I would like to add an "e-shock" "e-lean" (https://www.e-shock.it/products-item/e-lean-advanced/) inclinometer to a motorcycle which may not be equipped with CAN-BUS ECU.

For a display and datalogger I was hoping to use one of the MOTEC products
(https://www.motec.com.au/displays-currentrange/displays-directory/)

I understand that to function correctly the e-lean transducer requires speed information via the CANBUS,
so I would need some means of converting wheel distance pulses to CAN BUS data packets.

I would welcome any helpful comments, advice or suggestions (other than to not bother).

Thanks in advance.

Alan K.

p.s. The 2019 model of the Honda CB500F (twin) has fuel injection, abs and digital instrumentation, does anyone know whether this is based around CANBUS?

Comment: While the CB500F almost certainly has a CANBUS, as most modern ABS and FI equipped motorcycles do, that will probably not help you in the least.  The product you linked is an OEM product that will need programming support in order to be read. The ECU in your Honda will not be programmed to read this device so there will be no traffic from it for the MOTEC to "sniff" and display.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I was asking about the Honda CAN as I hoped that the wheel speed data messages might be available for the MOTEC display / logger to read.

Comment: I don't believe that Honda published their CANBUS messages but with some "sniffing" you can likely determine what's happening on the bus and decode it.  I'm not familiar with the MOTEC unit but I suspect it's somewhat programmable.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments.  I think that the best approach would be to have a completely separate MOTEC CAN system from that on the bike.